# Como calcular a raiz n-ésima de um número em C?

Tags: c

Tentei calcular assim, só que o `pow` retorna só o numero 1 pra mim :

```
int funcao1(int y,int z){
 int k;
 k = pow(y,1/z);
 return(k);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
double funcao1(int y,int z){
 double k;
 k = pow(y,1.0/z);
 return(k);
}
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
double raiz(int radicando, int indice){
  return pow(radicando, 1.0/indice);
}
```

O que mudou:

1) a raiz de um número pode ser fracionária, portanto é preciso retornar `float` ou `double` senão vai haver arredondamentos.

2) Como `z` é um inteiro e você estava fazendo `1/z`, esse resultado também vai ser inteiro, já que a constante `1` é tratada como inteira e C não faz a promoção automática do resultado de uma divisão de inteiros para `float` ou `double`. Se você passasse, digamos 4 e 2, a função ia elevar 4 a 1/2, mas 1/2 é zero quando convertemos pra inteiro (o arredondamento é pra baixo). Qualquer coisa elevada a zero é 1, por isso o resultado constante que você tava recebendo. A solução é usar `1.0` em vez de `1`, que força o tipo do resultado a ser `double`

Comment: Deu erro:->            iniciosimulado02.c: At top level:
iniciosimulado02.c:46:9: error: conflicting types for ‘funcao1’
  double funcao1(int y,int z){

Comment: Isso é porque você não alterou o protótipo da função. Vá para o topo do arquivo e mude o tipo de retorno do protótipo que está lá também.

Comment: continua mostrando apenas 1

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
int x=1;
imprimemenu();
questao03(x);
return(0);
}
int imprimemenu(){
printf("\n(1)  funcao  1\n");
printf("\n(2)  funcao  2\n");
printf("\n(3)  funcao  3\n");
printf("\n(0)  sair \n");
return(0);
}

Comment: Aqui está funcionando normalmente. [Veja você mesmo nesse link](https://ideone.com/0AOPXe).

Comment: tem como você me mandar o codigo inteiro para calcular a raiz n-ésima e mostrar o resultado

Comment: Não tinha Visto o link

Comment: Fiz a raiz igual você no meu codigo e a raiz calculada da totalmente diferente da correta.Segue o link do codigo: https://ideone.com/PUUXuU

Comment: Seus scanf e printf estão usando %i. Troque para %d quando for ler inteiro e %lf quando for imprimir double.

Comment: Nesse mesmo codigo meu menu só fecha quando o usuario seleciona todas as funções,ele deveria fechar quando o usuario digitar 0

Comment: Nesse caso eu sugiro que você abra uma nova pergunta específica pra esse caso. Já está saindo do foco da questão e está difícil acompanhar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67142/discussion-between-lucas-goncalves-and-pablo-almeida).